# Service won't start Android Studio, hovering button

Tags: android, service

I want to implement facebood head chat button like this:
https://github.com/henrychuangtw/Android-ChatHead
In my existing project, for projecting Chat button,

I copied the relevant parts of the github project like :

```
private void startChatHead(){
    Log.d(TAG,"at startChatHead().");
    startService(new Intent(FlightActivityUser.this, ChatHeadService.class));
}


private void showChatHeadMsg(){
    java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
    String str = "test by henry  " + new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(now);
    String EXTRA_MSG = "Yo";

    Intent it = new Intent(FlightActivityUser.this, ChatHeadService.class);
    it.putExtra(EXTRA_MSG, str);
    startService(it);
}

private void needPermissionDialog(final int requestCode){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FlightActivityUser.this);
    builder.setMessage("You need to allow permission");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    requestPermission(requestCode);
                }
            });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.show();
}

private void requestPermission(int requestCode){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE_CHATHEAD) {
        if (!canDrawOverlays(FlightActivityUser.this)) {
            needPermissionDialog(requestCode);
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG,"going to startChatHead()");
            startChatHead();
        }

    }else if(requestCode == OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE_CHATHEAD_MSG){
        if (!canDrawOverlays(FlightActivityUser.this)) {
            needPermissionDialog(requestCode);
        }else{
            showChatHeadMsg();
        }

    }

}

public static boolean canDrawOverlays(Context context){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return Settings.canDrawOverlays(context);
    }


}

Button.OnClickListener lst_StartService = new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "lst_StartService -> Utils.canDrawOverlays(Main.this): " + canDrawOverlays(FlightActivityUser.this));

        if(canDrawOverlays(FlightActivityUser.this))
            startChatHead();
        else{
            requestPermission(OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE_CHATHEAD);
        }
    }

};
```

And this log:

```
Log.d(TAG,"at startChatHead().");
startService(new Intent(FlightActivityUser.this, ChatHeadService.class));
```

Is being printed, and there the next line is the line that is supposed to start the service. But unfortunately the service won't start (I've checked with breakpoint and debugging and also with logs at onCreate and handleStart.

The signature of handle start is: `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    private void handleStart()`

What can I do in order to solve it? 
Or maybe have a better way to implement the facebook-like button for chat?

Thanks

Comment: Have you declared the service in the manifest ?

Comment: Thanks it fixed it.. I thought I copied all necessary things. Thanks.